# authenticating a client which sends same data all the time, no user accounts

Tags: security, authentication, client-server, communication, hash

I have a client that records button clicks, and i want to send how many times a button has been clicked every 20 seconds in an http message, and i want to avoid potential hackers who will send fake messages to the client. There are no user accounts, the client simply sends the number of clicks with no sessions or logins or anything like that.

I thought about sending a hash of the current time and date + some password and send the time and date unhashes for the server to authenticate. but how am going to implement it? I mean a hacker could be sending the same time and date and password all the time, so should i additionally check whether the time and date is within the last 5 minutes or something of that sort? Any tips?

It probably have been asked here before as it sounds like a very "common" thing, but i was sort of unsure about the relevant terminology regarding this issue and couldn't find an answer

Answer (score 0):

what you are trying to do is security by obscurity. --> hide your algorithm so noone will be able to reproduce the result.

basically a very bad idea. use existing authentification algorithms, they are prooved and better than all the things you come ever up with Possibility: el Gamal / DSA or RSA

You combine the following data and sign it with RSA:
- the message
- the actual time

with the public RSA key of the sender the receiver can check if the signature is correct.
you remember the dates of valid messages (if a message with a date which got already processed comes again it has to be an intercepted and resent message from a "hacker" so you dont process it even when the signature is correct)

Comment: Could you elaborate a little maybe proposing a solution tony problem specifically? Thanks.